# can we set svn:external for a single file in debian

Tags: svn-externals

can we set svn:external for a single file in debian

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can if can you use svn version >= 1.6.

http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.6_releasenotes.html#externals

...as drobert pointed out in a comment, svn 1.6 is still experimental in debian.

Comment: ... and since the question was "in debian" [sic], Subversion 1.6 is in testing, and will be released as part of Squeeze. Lenny still has 1.5. However, Michael Diers has made a backport: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.backports.general/5391

Answer (score 0):

[an externals definition can only point to directories, not files.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html)

Comment: this is only true for subversion < 1.6 since subversion 1.6 external can point to single files