# Single Image File to be SVN Externals

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I'm trying to add an image as `svn:externals` but TortoiseSVN refuses it somehow.

Currently I have two repositories on my local drive named `repoA` and `repoB`. Also there are two checkouts of working directories named `workA` and `workB`. `workA` is a checkout of `repoA` and `workB` is a checkout of `repoB`.

The structure is like this:

> Z:\repos\repoA
>
> Z:\repos\repoB
>
> Z:\Projects\workA
>
> Z:\Projects\workB

What I did:

1. right clicked on `Z:\Projects\workB` -> `TortoiseSVN -> Properties`
2. pressed `New -> Externals`
3. pressed `New`, typed `trunk/screenshot.jpg` for Local Path and `file:///Z:/repos/repoA/trunk/screenshot.jpg` for URL.

   [image]

   [image]
4. pressed `OK` to close all setting windows.
5. right clicked on `Z:\Projects\workB` -> `SVN Commit..`
6. right clicked on `Z:\Projects\workB` -> `SVN Update..`

And I get this error:

> Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\screenshot.jpg
>
> Unsupported external: url of file external
>
> 'file:///Z:/repos/repoA/trunk/screenshot.jpg' is not in repository
>
> 'file:///Z:/repos/repoB'

[image]

When I commit a new change on `workB/trunk`, it won't update the image. So performing `SVN Update` on `workB/trunk` does not import the image from repoA. I also have a folder imported as `svn:externals` and the files under it are imported properly. So I suspect a single file cannot be specified. I don't know.

In the repo-browser, the real file is not present there is only the link file.

[image]

In `repoA` there is the real image file although the error says there isn't.

[image]

So is it possible to do? Or am I doing it in the wrong way?

**Update**

According to [this article](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html),

> Subversion 1.6 also introduced support for external definitions for files. File externals are configured just like externals for directories and appear as a versioned file in the working copy.
>
> For example, let's say you had the file /trunk/bikeshed/blue.html in your repository, and you wanted this file, as it appeared in revision 40, to appear in your working copy of /trunk/www/ as green.html.

So it seems to be possible with v1.6 or above. And I'm using *svn, version 1.7.6 (r1370777)*.
Additional references:

- [can we set svn:external for a single file in debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371583/can-we-set-svnexternal-for-a-single-file-in-debian)
- [Can we set a single file as external in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355956/can-we-set-a-single-file-as-external-in-subversion)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is because you **can't use external files feature between two different repositories** (RepoA and repoB in your example).

Have a look to this limitation in the official doc:
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html

Abstract:

> The URL for a file external must be in the same repository as the URL that the file external will be inserted into; inter-repository file externals are not supported.

Comment: `you can't use external files feature between two different repositories` - It doesn't make sense to me because the `lib` folder is an externals and it is imported from `repoA`. Ahd files under the `lib` folder are imported without errors. How I've set up the lib folder as svn:externals is described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861082/setting-up-svnexternals-with-tortoisesvn-in-windows

Comment: Externals files (direct external on file) is a different feature from Externals folders (with files inside). Maybe this is where you are confused ?

Comment: `Externals files (direct external on file) is a different feature from Externals folders (with files inside).` - This is the question. Where does it say a file cannot be an externals but a directory can (also files under the directory can)?

Comment: According to [this article](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html), `Subversion 1.6 also introduced support for external definitions for files. File externals are configured just like externals for directories and appear as a versioned file in the working copy.` Also [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355956/can-we-set-a-single-file-as-external-in-subversion) tells that SVN had an issue with file externals in earlier versions prior to v1.6. I ran `svn --version` and it says `svn, version 1.7.6 (r1370777)` So the version I'm using seems to be okay.

Comment: I presume this is a limitation of the subversion clients, rather than of the subversion server.  Where do I look to see if the custodians of subversion are planning of fixing this?  Going from 1.8.13 to 1.9.2 did not seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it seems that you used to be able to have external files in Subversion 1.6 but that 'bug' is now fixed in subversion 1.7! and you can only have external folders from one repo to another, NOT files